# How to prevent Race Conditions using React Query?

Tags: reactjs, race-condition, react-query

I am new to React Query and I am trying to use the library to prevent race condition in my app.

I have a component that receives `id` as a prop and fetches the data accordingly and I am fetching the data using useQuery hook.

```
const Home = ({id}) => {
  const fetchData = async (signal) => {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?albumId=${id}`,
      { signal: signal }
    );
    return response.data;
  };

  const { data, error, status } = useQuery(["randomImages", id], ({ signal }) =>
  fetchData(signal)
);
  
  return (
    <main className="container">
      // return JSX
    </main>
  );
};
```

If the `id` prop changes frequently and several requests are made, how can I display the data corresponding to the last updated `id` and cancel all the previous requests?

Answer (score 2):

That's pretty much what your code is doing - is it not working?

Since `id` is part of the QueryKey, you will always get data that corresponds to that key. So if it changes frequently, the last requested `id` is displayed, no matter when the promise resolves. You can even do this without using the abort signal, in which case react-query will just keep the data cache under different keys for later usage. Using the provided signal just makes sure that queries that are no longer used (e.g. for ids that you are not using) will be cancelled.